# Jaspersoft Studio MongoDB connection authentication failure

Tags: mongodb, mlab, jaspersoft-studio

I'm attempting to connect Jaspersoft Studio 6.2.0 to a MongoDB database (mongod version: 3.0.7) hosted on MongoLab.

Using the connection URI:

```
 mongodb://ds012345-a0.mongolab.com:12345,ds012345-a1.mongolab.com:12345/mydb?replicaSet=rs-ds012345
```

[image]

I get the following exception when testing the adapter :

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "ds012345-a0.mongolab.com:12345" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "auth failed" , "code" : 18}
    at com.jaspersoft.mongodb.connection.MongoDbConnection.test(MongoDbConnection.java:162)
    at com.jaspersoft.mongodb.adapter.MongoDbDataAdapterService.test(MongoDbDataAdapterService.java:93)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.data.wizard.AbstractDataAdapterWizard$3.runOperations(AbstractDataAdapterWizard.java:162)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.utils.jobs.CheckedRunnableWithProgress$1.run(CheckedRunnableWithProgress.java:59)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "ds012345-a0.mongolab.com:12345" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "auth failed" , "code" : 18}
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:76)
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:131)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort$NativeAuthenticator.authenticate(DBPort.java:652)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.authenticate(DBPort.java:364)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.checkAuth(DBPort.java:375)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:291)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:271)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:84)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:317)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:296)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:371)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:243)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:397)
    at com.jaspersoft.mongodb.connection.MongoDbConnection.test(MongoDbConnection.java:158)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: You haven't passed username and password in connection string

Comment: I've entered them in the input fields below, rather than in the connection string.

Comment: Did you try passing the credentials with connection string?

Comment: Just tried it. Same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the [SCRAM-SHA-1](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/security-scram-sha-1/#authentication-scram-sha-1) authentication mechanism added in [MongoDB version 3.0](http://docs.mongolab.com/db-version-requirements/).

As mentioned in this [JasperReports Server issue](http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-server/issues/4976), the solution is to update the MongoDB Java driver by replacing the file:

```
Jaspersoft Studio-6.2.0.final\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\29\0\.cp\lib\mongo-java-driver-2.12.3.jar
```

with the one found here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/releases/download/r2.13.2/mongo-java-driver-2.13.2.jar

With the credentials in the URI, the connection succeeds.

Comment: Hi Francis, thank you for your answer.
However, it seems that whenever Jaspersoft Studio is launched, the old driver appears again in the folder (and is therefore used). Have you encountered that issue as well?

Comment: Ok, got it. The file `mongo-java-driver-2.13.2.jar` file has to be renamed to the original `mongo-java-driver-2.12.3.jar` Jasper filename. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MichaëlPerrin Hey mate, do you know how to connect to mongodb atlas database, In particular how to give URI in Jaspersoft Studio for a MongoDB connection

Comment: I am sorry @oshan2csd I have no idea. I don't even remember that issue actually :D